# Как прекратить отправку формы и продолжить по условию?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Имеется форма, в которой есть такой блок:

```
<fieldset class="box tabular" id="project_members">
    <legend>Members</legend>

                <div class="member-block">
      <input value="Robert Kovacik" name="members[[1][name]]" id="members_[1][name]" type="text">
          <input class="users_email" placeholder="Email, requred for new user" readonly="readonly" name="members[[1][email]]" id="members_[1][email]" type="text">

      <div class="member-roles-selection">
            <label><input name="[members][1][role_ids][0]" value="13" type="checkbox"> CEO</label>
            <label><input name="[members][1][role_ids][1]" value="3" type="checkbox"> Project Manager</label>
            <label><input name="[members][1][role_ids][2]" value="4" type="checkbox"> Consultant / Support</label>
            <label><input name="[members][1][role_ids][3]" value="7" type="checkbox"> Sales Representative</label>
            <label><input name="[members][1][role_ids][4]" value="10" type="checkbox"> Client</label>
            <label><input name="[members][1][role_ids][5]" value="12" type="checkbox"> IT expert</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="member-block">
      <input value="Dominka Helpdesk Coordinator" name="members[[2][name]]" id="members_[2][name]" type="text">
          <input class="users_email" placeholder="Email, requred for new user" readonly="readonly" name="members[[2][email]]" id="members_[2][email]" type="text">

      <div class="member-roles-selection">
            <label><input name="[members][2][role_ids][0]" value="13" type="checkbox"> CEO</label>
            <label><input name="[members][2][role_ids][1]" value="3" type="checkbox"> Project Manager</label>
            <label><input name="[members][2][role_ids][2]" value="4" type="checkbox"> Consultant / Support</label>
            <label><input name="[members][2][role_ids][3]" value="7" type="checkbox"> Sales Representative</label>
            <label><input name="[members][2][role_ids][4]" value="10" type="checkbox"> Client</label>
            <label><input name="[members][2][role_ids][5]" value="12" type="checkbox"> IT expert</label>
      </div>
    </div>
.............................. и т.д.
</fieldset>
```

До и после этого блока есть другие поля, у некоторых есть атрибут `required`.

Что хочу получить:
 У каждого блока `member-roles-selection` должна быть выбрана хотя бы одна роль, если не выбрана, то форму не отправлять и выдать ошибку. Так же должны работать html5 валидации.

Я пытался сделать это примерно таким образом:

```
$('#issue_tree').click(function(event) {
        var result = false;
        $(".member-roles-selection").each(function() {
            result = $(this).find(':checkbox:checked').length > 0;
            console.log(result);
            if(result === false){
                event.preventDefault();
                alert('error');
                return false;
            } else {
                result = false;
            }
        });
    });
```

Конкретно у этого кода проблема в том, что если один раз была показана ошибка, то форма не отправится уже никогда.
Если поменять `else` ветку на:

```
else {
    result = false;
    $('form').submit();
}
```

то игнорируются html5 валидации.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Грамотно поставленный вопрос - половина ответа. Как это часто бывает, сразу после вопроса, самостоятельно находится ответ.

Сейчас у меня js выглядит примерно так:

```
$('#issues_tree').click(function(event) {
        var result = false;
        $(".member-roles-selection").each(function() {
            result = $(this).find(':checkbox:checked').length > 0;
            if(!result){
                event.preventDefault();
                alert('error');
            } else {
                result = false;
            }
        });
    });
```